# sum values of a column over distinct values of other column

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm using sybase database, an extraction of my table would be :

```
ClientNumber|ArticlesBought|TotalAllowed
2223        |2             |20
2223        |1             |20
2226        |3             |25
2226        |2             |25
2227        |1             |20
```

What I need is to calculate the sum of all the articlesBought and devide it by the sum of the total allowed for the distinct clients.

```
sum(ArticlesBought) = 9 and sum(TotalAllowed)= 65 and not 110
```

My first question is can I do this in one query?
I tried using:

```
select sum(TotalAllowed)
from myTable
group by ClientNumber
```

but it returns 40, 45 and 20, which is wrong.
Could you please help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
         Select my.ClientNumber  ,     my2.TotalArticlesBought/ClientData.TotalAllowedperClient from tblFabSource my
    inner join (select sum(Distinct TotalAllowed)as     TotalAllowedperClient,ClientNumber from myTable group by ClientNumber)    
    ClientData on ClientData .ClientNumber=my.ClientNumber  
    inner join (select sum(ArticlesBought)as TotalArticlesBought from     myTable ) my2   
      on my2.TotalArticlesBought>0
```

Comment: I get an error saying that my.ClientNumber must appear in a group by

Comment: I have edited the query.Please check if this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the query works however it returns the result for every clientNumber, but what I need is the total for everyone, in the example above 9/65

Comment: Replace Sum(TotalAllowed) with sum(Distinct TotalAllowed).Edited the query above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(articlesbought), SUM(DISTINCT totalallowed) from tablename
```

you can use a distinct on the sum of totalallowed

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however there can be an other client with TotalAllowed 20, in that case, the query will return a wrong result (I'll edit my question)

Comment: @Jean Add `Group By ClientNumber` at the end to @@Bennjoe Mordeno query.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza you were right, adding the group by ClintNumber solves the issue of two clients having the same totalAllowed, but I don't get the sum of all the total allowed, I get the totalAllowed per Client